# How can I add a string to an array of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I have a string "token" and an empty array of strings "arr". I want to add token to the first index of arr. I've tried `arr[0][0] = token`, but this would only work for chars and I've also tried `arr[0] = token` but this throws the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". My full program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char arr[100][100] = {};
char *token = strtok(StringToBeSplit, " ");
int i = 0;

while(token != NULL) {
    arr[0] = token;
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Using a string literal with strtok invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: This sort of problem should be dealt with by working through a C textbook, primer, or course. String handling is an elementary skill taught in the normal course of learning to program. Stack Overflow should not be used as a substitute for studying. It takes work to acquire the skills and knowledge to program, and attempting to use shortcuts like asking specific questions on isolated tasks is not a good way to learn thoroughly.

Comment: In C, the programmer is responsible for manually managing strings. If you keep an array `char arr[100][100]`, then you must copy strings into the array, which you can do with `strcpy(arr[i], source)` (and you must ensure they fit). You can also keep an array of pointers to strings, `char *arr[100]`, and then you can assign elements of the array to point to strings, `arr[i] = source`. However, you must then manage the memory, allocating appropriate memory for each string to be saved. (You cannot use the same memory for `source` over and over again.)

Comment: Also, if you want to initialize the array, use `char arr[100][100] = {{0}};`, not `char arr[100][100] = {};`. Some compilers may accept an empty initializer list, but the proper form is to have at least one initializer, and preferably nested to match the type of the object being initialized. However, it may be unnecessary to initialize this array at all, if it is set and used properly later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid assigning string literal to strtok. Basically using strcpy to copy the token to array and increment array as advised by previous answer. Something like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char arr[100][100] = {};
char str[] = "Split this string";
char sep[] = " ";
char *token = strtok(str, sep);
int i = 0;
while(token != NULL){
    strcpy(arr[i], token);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    i++;
}

//Test If it can print the strings
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%s\n", arr[j]);

 }
```

Comment: String literals are not the cause of the problem or the subject of the question. The question states (after an edit, prior to this answer) that the actual code does not use string literals; they are just in the question for illustration.

Comment: Got it, the issue was actually strcpy and i've addressed it in the answer